# Is it possible to traverse a class to see if a class or any of it's bases have a particular trait?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have a class `X1`, which derives from `Y` and another class `X2`.  `Y` and `X2` have a particular trait `Z_trait`.

Now I have a template function and I want to check that the parameter has a particular trait.

This is what I have:

```
#include<type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Y       {};
struct X1 : Y<int>  {};
struct X2      {};
struct Z_trait {};

template <typename Container>
struct has_trait;

template <>
struct has_trait<X2>
{
  typedef Z_trait type;
};

template <typename T>
struct has_trait<Y<T>>
{
  typedef Z_trait type;
};

template <typename Container>
void fn(Container& container)
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<typename has_trait<Container>::type, Z_trait>::value
    , "must have Z_trait");
  Container* x = &container;
  ++x;
}

int main()
{
  X1 x1;
  X2 x2;
  Y<char> y;

  fn(x1);
  fn(x2);
  fn(y);

  return 0;
}
```

<kbd>demo</kbd>

I want it so that `has_trait` will give the `Z_trait` for all three types.  How would I do this?  Is there a way of iterating over all base classes, or is there some easier method to test for a trait?

NOTE that I am not using a using template.  The reason for this is that VS2013 doesn't support this fully.

Oh, and FYI, I don't want to change the implementation of `X1`, `X2` or `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to specialize `has_trait<>` for the descendants as well, not just for the base:

```
#include<type_traits>

struct Y       {};
struct X1 : Y  {};
struct X2      {};
struct Z_trait {};

template <typename Container, typename = void>
struct has_trait;

template <typename T> 
struct has_trait<T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of<X2, T>::value >::type >
{
  typedef Z_trait type;
};

template <typename T> 
struct has_trait<T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of<Y, T>::value >::type >
{
  typedef Z_trait type;
};

template <typename Container>
void fn(Container& container)
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<typename has_trait<Container>::type, Z_trait>::value
    , "must have Z_trait");
  Container* x = &container;
  ++x;
}

int main()
{
  X1 x1;
  X2 x2;
  Y y;

  fn(x1);
  fn(x2);
  fn(y);

  return 0;
}
```

Also, you might consider a `static constexpr const bool has_z_trait = true;` or a `static bool hasTrait(const ZTrait&) { return true; }`, it makes the static assert simpler imho.

Comment: The reason why I'm using types rather than value is that I'm using type traits from the std library.  This sort of works, but if X1 is a template, it doesn't work.  I get a 'is not deductible in partial specialization` error if I try and add the template arguments to the list.

Comment: @Adrian: You have to *"fix"* your traits if `Y` is template: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46f9d20bc37a27bd).

Comment: That's excellent.  Post that to the answer and I'll mark it as done. :)